# php mysql join same table

Tags: php, mysql, join

Is it possible to join from the same table?

my database

```
╔════╦══════╦════════╗
║ id ║ name ║ Leader ║
╠════╬══════╬════════╣
║  1 ║ Eric ║   2    ║
║  2 ║ Ivan ║   0    ║
╚════╩══════╩════════╝
```

What I want to show is (`id` = 1 , `name` = Eric , `Leader` = Ivan)

This is my query:

```
$result= mysql_query("SELECT member.*, leader.* from table AS member
                      INNER JOIN table AS leader ON member.id = leader.id
                      WHERE member.id = ... 
                     ");
```

Comment: Yes, it is called **SELF JOIN** (very common for hierarchy)

Comment: @lad2025 can you help me? I cant do it.

Comment: `SELECT member.id, member.name, leader.name AS leader FROM table as member JOIN table as leader ON member.leader = leader.id WHERE member.id = 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a self join query which will achieve what you want:

```
SELECT member.name AS name, leader.name AS leader
FROM table AS member
INNER JOIN table AS leader
    ON member.Leader = leader.id
WHERE member.id = 1
```